# How do I write a bash script that prints every line of one file also in second file

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

for example, I have 2 text files :

file1 consists of:

```
a 
b
```

file2 consists of:

```
a
ab
bc 
c
```

output should be:

```
$p1.sh file1 file2 
a
ab
bc
```

how exactly would I code this in Linux?

Comment: First im a bit confused can you tell me why you wont this for context

Comment: I think, you have wrong result for the second case `$p1.sh file2 file1`. The answer should be `cc` and not `c`. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the second example (`p1.sh file2 file1`) should output `cc` as there is no line with just `c` in `file1`. If so, then:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat "$1" | while read m  
do
    grep "$m" "$2"
done | sort -u
```

example:

```
$ cat f1
a
b
bb
b
cc
$ cat f2
aa
ab
bc
c
$ ./p1.sh f1 f2
aa
ab
bc
$ ./p1.sh f2 f1
cc
```

Comment: thank you! could you explain the logic in this code please

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with grep only

```
grep -f file1 file2
grep -f file2 file1
```