# How do I write a script that prints every line of a file that is not contained in a another file? (Bash script)

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, printing, text-processing

for example, I have 2 text files :

file1 consists of:

```
a 
b
bb
cc
```

file2 consists of:

```
aa
bc
ab
```

output should be:

```
$p1.sh file1 file2 
bb
cc

$p1.sh file2 file1
aa
bc
ab
```

how would I write this bash script?
I was writing something like this but it was not working:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat "$1" | while read m  
do
    grep -f -v "$m" "$2"
done | sort -u
```

any sort of guidance would be appreciated! I am a beginner programmer and have no experience in writing scripts. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a bash script that prints every line of one file also in second file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362883/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-that-prints-every-line-of-one-file-also-in-second-f)

Comment: @mikewhatever Unfortunately no, that link looks at common lines, but here I am trying to print lines that are not common. The complete opposite task! :)

Comment: `-f <file>` option takes a file as an argument. The file is actually a pattern list (one pattern per line). If you are trying to match literally, you should add `-F` too.

Comment: It this homewotk? What does it have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: I gave you a sympathy upvote, but I'm beginning to see why it's received so many downvotes. *You* asked the opposite question a few days ago, you haven't answered "why" you would need this either time (leading us to believe you want us to do your homework for you), and the second answer provided on your other question simply needs one flag to be changed to (hint) invert the answer, which you should be able to find if you had tried that answer and `man grep` to see the options.  If it's not a homework question, it's an XY problem[https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/902710].

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the commands sort and comm for this job. For example:

```
comm -23 <(sort -u file1.txt) <(sort -u file2.txt) > file3.txt
```

I will leave it to you to play with the suppression flags (-1,-2,-3) for the desired outcome. I have used -23 as an example.

Another perhaps easier method is using awk as follows:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{lines[$0]=1;next} !($0 in lines)' file1 file2
```